# How to use DocuementReference with class-transformer?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, nestjs, class-transformer

I'm using `ClassSerializerInterceptor` in my NestJS application to apply `instanceToPlain` when I return objects on incoming requests. I also use firestore as my main database. Some of my entities contains `DocumentReference` which I want to directly return without applying every time `@Transform` on it. When I do so, I got following error in my console:

> ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Value for argument "documentPath" is not a
> valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string. Error: Value for
> argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a
> non-empty string.

I was trying to fix this by myself and found package [class-transformer-firestore](https://github.com/RonasIT/class-transformer-firestore) which seems to be potential solution, but it use `prototype` and have no readme at all, so I have no idea how to use it. I tried just to install it with no success.

Maybe someone faced the same issue and have solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Please check original repo again, seems like author updated it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).